# Sencha Architect - create new --> Unable to import archived project, when I choose from an existing template

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I installed the trial version of Sencha Architect, currently in Day 14.

Initially it was working fine, and i created a project from scratch. But now, when I try to Create New --> and choose a template like Sencha Touch 2.3-->Examples -->City Bars or Sencha Touch 2.3-->Basic -->Login/Register, I keep getting an error message saying "Unable to Import Archived Project"

Any advice?

Thanks